# Laravel CSRF token expire

Tags: javascript, laravel, csrf-protection

I am new to Laravel 5.4 and have just created a login form. The thing which I have noticed is, if I left the login for some 2 hrs and returned back, my csrf token would get expire. Is it possible to show a javascript alert box that the session has expired and after clicking the OK button it will take me to the login page again?

Comment: You can catch the token expiry when the user submits the login form and redirect them back to the form with an error message saying "Login session has expired. Please try again", or something similar.

Comment: Are you sure you meant csrf or session expiring?

Comment: The session duration is 120 minutes by default, the csrf token expires since it uses session store. It's the same thing.

Comment: I was expecting something in JavaScript that would check for csrf token expiry.

Comment: I have seen on some site, when u left the site login it would automatically show u the msg that ur session expired and u must login again.

Comment: A simple solution to be to start a timer in js when the page loads and then when the timer hits your session expiration time, trigger the alert box. Easy and clean solution.

Comment: Doesnt this timer interrupts my other js code from processing?

Comment: How do you mean "interrupts my other js code from processing"? I think @Sandeesh has a great answer to this. You just create a timer in JS that will count down the time (independently of your other code) and when that time is over it pops out an alert that you need to login or refresh or something.

Comment: @codelearner no they won't, this method is very simple and suit your need perfectly

Comment: Isn't this js a single-threaded and running a timer on the same thread will stop execution of other code for a while because its synchronous job.

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like In your view. using the `auth` helper function.

```
@if (! auth()->check())
      <script type="text/javascript">
                alert('session expired!!')
      </script>
@endif
```

**Edit:**

Okay the above function runs only once when the page is loaded and does not meet OPs requirements so to solve this we can try and  directly catch the `token-mismatch` exception in the back-end side.

So In method `render()` of `/app/Exceptions/Handler.php` you could try something like:

```
if ( $e instanceof \Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException ) {
    return redirect()->route('login');
}
```

Comment: What if he is just not logged in? Wouldn't that fire but there was no session to begin with?

Comment: This would run only when the page is loaded. I don't think that's what he wanted.

Comment: This is not a time based check. If the session was to expire after an hour of login, this wont work.

Comment: @SapneshNaik i recommended this to the author and he wishes for a simpler solution. The exception catch you've posted works perfect. But also in a normal application you would want to redirect back to the previous page.

Comment: @Sandeesh I would say this is the simplest and most efficient way to do it. As this takes care of the issue at a the entire site level and not just on a particular page. and we can easily use `redirect()->back()` to send the use back instead of redirecting back to the login page.

Comment: That would be my suggestion. But the author wants to have some check on the same page even before the user performs an action which would inevitably fail. I've also suggested him this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44045394/laravel-csrf-token-expire/44045461?noredirect=1#comment75116981_44045394